# How can I change the redirect path after login and logout in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, laravel-5.3, logout

I have changed the protected $redirectTo = '/tasks'; in both the LoginController and RegisterController.
Also, I have changed the redirect path in the middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated as follows:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/tasks');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Even though I have done these changes, nothing works, and the pages are redirected to the /login path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `$redirectTo` will take effect after you have logged in. First of all you need to login. That's why it's sending you to `/login` path. So if you want to change where it redirects after `Login` or `Registration`, you change those `$redirectTo` properties. If you don't want a user to login at all, you should remove the `auth` middleware for that route.

EDIT:
So what you have missed is that laravel redirects you back to the intended page and if there is none it will redirect to $redirectTo. So if you try to go to homepage and that needs authenticated user, after login it redirects back to the homepage and not /tasks because that's where you were trying to go. If you want to always redirect to that path and not to intended path you can do something as below.

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return redirect()->to($this->redirectTo);
}
```

Add this code to your `LoginController` and you will always be redirected to `$redirectTo`.

Comment: I just want to be redirected to the /tasks path.  How can that be done?

Comment: What do you mean? You mean always redirected to that path?

Comment: If a user is logged in successfully then I need a redirect to that path e.g. /tasks.

Comment: If a user log out then I need to set another path.

Comment: by changing $redirectTo you should be redirected to that path. Maybe there is something else wrong. Is it laravels's own authentication system including login form and everything?

Comment: Everything is working fine. Except if I need to change the redirect. My version of laravel is 5.3

Comment: Yes, it's laravel's own authentication system.

Comment: So where does it redirect after successful login right now? After you have changed $redirectTo I mean

Comment: It redirects to the default path of the laravel's own login system.

Comment: Go to the login page directly, by visiting http://yoursite.com/login and see after login it redirects to /tasks.

Comment: Yes it works. But how can I do it to automatically send me to the required path after login?

Comment: Why does it work with the code you suggested? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Well it's simply overriding a method from AuthenticateUsers trait ... in this method we are only changing the last line. If you take at this method in that trait, you will see what is changed.

Comment: Why it is not working by simply changing the redirectTo property?

Comment: READ the edit part in my answer, I have fully explained it and you can also take a look at the code. It's right there.

Comment: It's not fully explained. Why after login it redirects to the homepage?

Comment: It is not supposed to be fully explained. You should check out the code and try to figure it out. But redirecting user to where he intended to go is pure common sense.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code, I got that your IF statement is not returning true. You have to first see, what is it returning. Also, redirect to your desired location without any condition just to test the code.

Also, I am using this code for redirection after login in my application.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: In the official documentation of Laravel it says that you only need to change the $redirectTo property. But it's not working that way. Even if I change the middleware it is not working. I don't know why you have to put the code Farzin Farzanehnia suggested.